# How to iterate through an array of objects and return one that has a specific object ID using JSX (in mapStateToProps of React-Redux)

Tags: arrays, object, react-redux, return, mapstatetoprops

I am trying to pass an object (called a lecture) to the props from state using mapStateToProps.  The object exists in an array of objects.  I believe I am making a syntax error but am uncertain on exactly what is the correct syntax should be because the code below works for cycling through a parent object (that contains objects inside of it) and select the correct object inside of the parent.

```
//This code works to cycle through a parent Object that contains objects inside of it; returning the object inside that has the correct ID.
//It doesn't work in this situation ... where instead of having objects inside a parent object, 
//there are obejcts inside a parent Array.

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    const lectureID = state.selectedLectureID;
    console.log(lectureID);          <--- THIS SHOWS THE CORRECT ID OF THE OBJECT I AM TRYING TO READ.

    const lectures = state.firestore.ordered.lectures;
    console.log(lectures);        <------ THIS SHOWS THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS, INCLUDING ONE OBJECT THAT HAS THE LECTURE ID FOUND ABOVE


    const selectedLecture= lectures ? lectures[lectureID] : null; <--- ERROR HERE... TRYING TO CYCLE THROUGH THE ARRAY OF LECTURES AND PASS THE LECTURE THAT HAS THE CORRECT LECTURE ID. IF NONE HAVE THIS ID, THEN IT SHOULD RETURN "null".
    console.log(selectedLecture);   <--- THIS RETURNS "undefined", SUGGESTING THE CODE ABOVE DIDN'T READ THROUGH THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS AND SELECT THE ONE WITH THE CORRECT ID.
    

return {

        selectedLecture: selectedLecture,
        
    }
}
```

**NOTE: The code above appears interpret the lectureID as an index in the array rather than an attempt to identify the objects ID within the array of Objects. How can I correct this?**

Answer (score 0):

**I FOUND AN ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**

Instead of trying to iterate across the array of objects inside mapStateToProps, I found it easier to simply pass the object with the specific ID as an object through Actions + Reducers, and interacting with the content via the state.